# If $X$ is a complete, separable, and perfect metric space, then a map $f$ is topologically transitive if and only if it has a dense orbit.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a complete, separable, and perfect metric space. I'm trying to show that for map $f : X \rightarrow X$, topological transitivity is equivalent to having a dense orbit.

Dense orbit $\implies$ transitivity: Let $U, V \subset X$. Since there exists $x \in X$ such that $\text{Orb}(x) = \{x, f(x), f^2(x), \dots\} = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots\}$ is dense in $X$, then there exist $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n := f^n(x) \in U$ and $x_m := f^m(x) \in V$. WLOG assume $n>m$. Since $x_n \in f^{n-m}(\{x_m\})$, then $x_n \in U \cap f^{n-m}(V)$, therefore $f$ is transitive.

I don't know how to show the inverse though, how would I prove that transitivity implies dense orbit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{U_k\}$ be a countable basis for the topology.  For each $k$ let $V_k$ be the elements of $X$ that visit $U_k$ after some number of applications of $f$.  Then $V_k$ is open and dense.  By the Baire category theorem, $\cap_k V_k$ is nonempty.  An element of this intersection has a dense orbit.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but how do we know that $V_k$ is open and dense?

Comment: No, good question. open is from continuity of $f^j$ ($j\in \mathbb{N}$): if $f^j(x)\in U$, then $f^j(W)\subset U$ for some open neighborhood $W$ of $x$. Density is from "topological transitivity": If $V_k$ is not dense, there exists open nonempty $W$ s.t. $f^j(W)\cap U_k=\emptyset$ for all $j$.